Why are some emails not being moved to trash using Gmail API in a batch process?
I'm working on a Node.js application using NestJS and the Gmail API to move emails to trash in batches. However, users are reporting that not all emails are being moved to trash. For example, out of 140,000 emails, only 80,000 are successfully trashed. I'm using the batchModify method to add the TRASH label and remove the INBOX label.
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job } from 'bull';
import { gmail_v1 } from 'googleapis';
import { prisma } from 'src/database/prisma';
import { GmailService } from 'src/gmail/gmail.service';

@Processor('DELETE_SENDER_EMAILS_QUEUE')
export class DeleteSenderEmailsProcessor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(DeleteSenderEmailsProcessor.name);
  private readonly MAX_RETRIES = 5;
  private readonly INITIAL_DELAY = 1000; // 1 second

  constructor(private readonly gmailService: GmailService) {}

  @Process({ concurrency: 20 })
  async deleteSenderEmails(job: Job<{ userId: string; senderEmail: string }>) {
    const { userId, senderEmail } = job.data;
    this.logger.log(`Starting to delete emails from ${senderEmail} for user ${userId}`);

    try {
      await this.processDeletionForSender(userId, senderEmail);
      this.logger.log(`Finished processing deletions for user ${userId} and sender ${senderEmail}`);
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(`Error processing deletions for user ${userId} and sender ${senderEmail}:`, error);
    }
  }

  private async processDeletionForSender(userId: string, senderEmail: string) {
    const gmail = await this.gmailService.getGmailInstance(userId);
    const query = `from:${senderEmail}`;
    const batchSize = 500;
    let nextPageToken: string | undefined = undefined;

    do {
      const searchResponse = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: 'me',
        q: query,
        maxResults: batchSize,
        pageToken: nextPageToken,
      });

      const messages = searchResponse.data.messages || [];
      const messageIds = messages.map((message) => message.id).filter((id): id is string => !!id);

      if (messageIds.length === 0) {
        break;
      }

      const categoryLabels = ['INBOX', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL', 'CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS', 'CATEGORY_UPDATES', 'CATEGORY_FORUMS'];

      for (let i = 0; i < messageIds.length; i += 1000) {
        const chunk = messageIds.slice(i, i + 1000);
        await gmail.users.messages.batchModify({
          userId: 'me',
          requestBody: {
            ids: chunk,
            addLabelIds: ['TRASH'],
            removeLabelIds: categoryLabels,
          },
        });
      }

      nextPageToken = searchResponse.data.nextPageToken;
    } while (nextPageToken);
  }
}

What I've Tried:

Error Handling: I've added error handling and logging to capture any issues during the batchModify operation.

Rate Limiting: Implemented retry logic with exponential backoff for rate limit errors.
Batch Size: Ensured that the batch size does not exceed Gmail API limits.


Questions:

Are there any known issues with the Gmail API's batchModify method that could cause some emails to be skipped?
Could there be a problem with the way I'm handling pagination or batch processing?
Are there any additional logging or debugging steps I should take to identify the root cause?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
